# poor performance for neo4j on Microsoft Azure

Tags: performance, azure, neo4j

I have deployed a neo4j D.B on microsoft Azure , it takes so long (2-3 seconds) to make connection and a much longer time ( 5- 7 seconds!) on making a simple queries , like:

```
client.Cypher.Match("(recipe:Recipe)")
            .Where("recipe.name = {name} AND recipe.whoMadeItEmail = {mader}")
            .WithParams(parameters)
            .Return(recipe => recipe.As<Recipe>())
            .Results;
```

it's so frustrating , we're developing a web and two applications for startup and we're struggling with the this poor performance , I also keep getting this weird error that the cord is unplugged!
I run it on a ubuntu 12.04 
neo4j version : 2.0.1
virtual machine : A4 (8 cores , 14GB memory)

what's wrong !!! ?

Comment: As the question stands, there's not much to go on, and it's not really possible to diagnose the issue (not even sure yet if it's programming-related or if this should be moved to ServerFault). Can you please edit your question to give more info on where you're connecting from (specifically: Is it from a VM/website in the same region)? Also, keep in mind that A4 is a fairly old generation. Have you benchmarked on a D12? (same price, much faster hardware plus SSD temp drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Neo4j VM available through the Microsoft Azure image depot is out of date. I advise deploying Neo4j to Microsoft Azure using Docker. You can find the latest available Docker image for Neo4j community here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/kbastani/docker-neo4j/

Also, you can use Elastic Beanstalk through Amazon EC2 using SSDs for better performance.

If you're set on Microsoft Azure's limited support for Docker, you can follow this guide: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-docker-vm-extension/

Comment: Not sure of the relevance of Elastic Beanstalk, since this is an Azure deployment. And as I commented on the question, a D12 has local SSD, which can be used for storage if an HA solution is deployed across multiple nodes (along with appropriate backup scheme).

Comment: Hey David, the Elastic Beanstalk deployment works great with Docker. That's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you

Create index on :Recipe(name)

?